# Reports based on Lists for SharePoint online

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, reporting-services, reports

One of our clients use SharePoint Online & uses a simple lists-based case management system. They want to receive weekly report in email based on the data in lists, preferably using **configuration** (or designer).

I see there are two components here, actual reporting engine capable of talking to Online SharePoint (preferably in cloud) & second would be a scheduled workflow to shoot email if engine already does not do this.

I searched a lot for solutions from likes of Bamboo or hosted SSRS, but could not find anything for SharePoint Online.

Has anyone come across any product or useful strategy in this regard.

My last option is Custom Workflow using Visual Studio which will dump static data in excel/pdf/html & send it as an attachment.

Comment: I tried [OData Connector](http://www.rssbus.com/odata/?tabs=3) from rssbus which looks promising but could not figure out how to connect to it from SSRS/Report Builder :(

Answer (score 1):

We recently released [Workflow Scheduler for SharePoint Online](http://plumsail.com/workflow-scheduler/). This app will help you to schedule your workflows to run periodically.

Out of the box workflow action 'Send an Email' doesn't allow to send message with attachment. To send an e-mail with attachment you can use other our product [Workflow Actions Pack](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/). It provides set of [e-mail processing workflow actions](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/actions-description/).

Note: Both products are paid, but cheap enough.

Answer (score 0):

Reflex Reporting for SharePoint Online => http://www.thorapps.com/Pages/SharePointReporting.aspx

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Azure Job or Scheduler and connect to SharePoint Online with the help of console tool. Bring that data to the SQL Azure or any other environment where you want to sync. That way it will periodically bring the data and send emails.

Reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/scheduler/